# Facebook OAuth redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":191

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, oauth, oauth2client

I've been struggling this afternoon to put my application using facebook oauth.
I am getting an error while trying to get the access token:

```
{\"error\":{\"message\":\"redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":191}}
```

Here is my request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=AQD0...3X0v5EKU&client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXX&redirect_uri=http%253a%252f%252flocalhost%252fMySite.Web%252fAccount%252fExternalLoginCallback%253fReturnUrl%253d%252fMySite.Web%252fAbout%252fIndex%2526__provider__%253dfacebook%2526__sid__%253d19cdb2fdc733479fa3c2df14531064a7
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `redirect_uri` starts `http://localhost` - This type of URL wouldn't work for almost all users of your app, and isn't allowed by Facebook as a redirect URL - it would never be retrievable from outside your own machine, for example.

You can likely work around that if you're testing on localhost by setting up another DNS entry which resolves to your local machine and use that instead - many machines setup 'localhost.localdomain' as a local DNS name for that purpose

Comment: You mean http://localhost.localdomain/MySite.Web... I receive the same error. 

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=xxx&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&redirect_uri=http%253a%252f%252flocalhost.localdomain%252fMySite.Web%252fAccount%252fExternalLoginCallback%253fReturnUrl%253dhttp%253a%252f%252flocalhost.localdomain%252fMySite.Web%252fAbout%252fIndex%2526__provider__%253dfacebook%2526__sid__%253d250bad8027084ba09480d0aee9f58f74

Comment: From that example it looks like your redirect_uri is double-encoded, I see:
`http%253a%252f%252flocalhost.localdomain` ... 
shouldn't it be `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost.localdomain` ?

Comment: If I try to do this:https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=XXX&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost.localdomain%2fMySite.Web%2fAccount%2fExternalLoginCallback%3fReturnUrl%3dhttp%3a%2f%2flocalhost.localdomain%2fMySite.Web%2fAbout%2fIndex%26__provider__%3dfacebook%26__sid__%3de05f31cdeb924167912c8b2030436c45 I will get other error: {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

Comment: And was the redirect_uri identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request?

Comment: Yes it is. The url on facebook config is http://localhost.localdomain/MyPortfolio.Web/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl=%2FMyPortfolio.Web%2FAbout%2FIndex  could it be a problem in the ending part of the url? Because I have some parameters that are another url "ReturnUrl=%2FMyPortfolio.Web%2FAbout%2FIndex"

Comment: You were right, when calling OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication (.net class for OpenAuth) it was including an extra parameter.In the end I got rid of the 2nd parameter in the callbacl url and it worked well. So, now I am only passing this url "http://localhost.localdomain/MyPortfolio.Web/Account/ExternalLoginCallback" Thanks

Comment: Why do you say that it's not a URL compliant with RFC3986?

Comment: Good catch - I should have said 'isn't a resolvable URL compliant...' or 'accessible URL...' you're correct that the URL format itself was fine; will edit